# multithreading or forking in perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, fork

in my perl script I'm collecting a large data and later I need it to post to server, up to this I'm good but my criteria is that post to server takes subsequently large time so I need to a threading / forking concept so that one will post and parallely I can dig my second data set at same time while posting to server is taking place.

code snippet

```
if(system("curl -sS $post_url --data-binary \@$filename -H 'Content-type:text/xml;charset=utf-8' 1>/dev/null") != 0)
        {
            exit_script(" xml: Error ","Unable to update $filename xml on $post_url");
        }
```

can any one tell me is this achievable with threading or forking.

Comment: You can execute your curl in background with '&'. but then you need its pid to know when it finished and what was the status.

Comment: thank you very much but I missed my actual query. In my function I  should return a result if I found it and same time if that result is old (according to our indexed date) I need to update it same time but I don't want my controller to wait till I update it needs to return the old result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to give an answer to your question, because it depends.

Yes, Perl supports both forking and threading.

In general, I would suggest looking at threading for data-oriented tasks, and forking for almost anything else.

And so what you want to so is eminently achievable.

First you need to:

- Encapsulate your tasks into subroutines. Get that working first. (This is very important - parallel stuff causes worlds of pain and is difficult to troubleshoot if you're not careful - get it working single threaded first).
- Run your subroutines as threads, and capture their results.

Something like this:

```
use threads;

sub curl_update {
   my $result = system ( "you_curl_command" );
   return $result; 
}

#start the async curl

 my $thr = threads -> create ( \&curl_update ); 

 #do your other stuff....
 sleep ( 60 ); 

 my $result = $thr -> join(); 
 if ( $result ) { 
       #do whatever you would if the curl update failed
 }
```

In this, the `join` is a blocking call - your main code will stop and wait for your thread to complete. If you want to do something more complicated, you can use `is_running` or `is_joinable` which are non blocking.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest neither.

You're just talking lots of HTTP. You can talk concurrent HTTP a lot nicer, because it's just network IO, by using any of the asynchronous IO systems. Perl has many of them.

Principally I'd suggest `IO::Async`, but then I wrote it. You can use `Net::Async::HTTP` to make an HTTP hit. This will fully support doing many of them at once - many hundreds or thousands if need be.

Otherwise, you can also try either `POE` or `AnyEvent`, which will both support the same thing in their own way.